# OpenCV manual build. No such file or directory #include "generated_16.i"

Tags: c++, opencv, python

I'm trying to build OpenCV in docker container based on centos. I can't use ubuntu which already have precompiled packages. During build i'm getting error 'No such file or directory #include "generated_16.i"' and 'No such file or directory #include "normal_lut.i"'. Do you know what libraries i'm missing? I can't find any info where those libraries belongs.

````
[2020-07-21T08:01:51.817Z] [91m/tmp/opencv_contrib/modules/rgbd/src/linemod.cpp:593:24: fatal error: normal_lut.i: No such file or directory
[2020-07-21T08:01:51.817Z]  #include "normal_lut.i"
[2020-07-21T08:01:51.817Z]                         ^
[2020-07-21T08:01:51.817Z] compilation terminated.
[2020-07-21T08:01:52.074Z] [0m[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_rgbd.dir/src/nonrigid_icp.cpp.o
[2020-07-21T08:01:52.639Z] [91mmake[2]: *** [modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_rgbd.dir/src/linemod.cpp.o] Error 1
[2020-07-21T08:01:52.639Z] make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[2020-07-21T08:01:52.639Z] [0m[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_video.dir/src/lkpyramid.cpp.o
[2020-07-21T08:01:52.639Z] [ 72%] Processing OpenCL kernels (xfeatures2d)
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.203Z] Scanning dependencies of target opencv_xfeatures2d
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.203Z] [ 73%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/affine_feature2d.cpp.o
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.460Z] [ 73%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/boostdesc.cpp.o
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.717Z] [ 73%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/brief.cpp.o
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.974Z] [91m/tmp/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/brief.cpp:126:26: fatal error: generated_16.i: No such file or directory
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.974Z]  #include "generated_16.i"
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.974Z]                           ^
[2020-07-21T08:01:53.974Z] compilation terminated.
[2020-07-21T08:01:54.906Z] [0m[91mmake[2]: *** [modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/brief.cpp.o] Error 1
[2020-07-21T08:01:54.906Z] make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs..```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same problem and I've just figured out what the problem was.
I downloaded the opencv repo and then pushed it into a local git repo and then pulled it from another machine, the `*.i` extension was added by git to the `.gitignore` automatically so the file didn't get pushed.
When I removed it and pushed again, the problem was fixed.